# What can be the best way to use captcha with spring boot and react application?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-redux, recaptcha, captcha

I want to implement captcha for my application which has frontend on React JS and backend on Spring boot. For implementing captcha, I found many solutions like google's recaptcha, botdetect library etc.
But I am bit confused what should be the best way and flow to use captcha for my application. I want to pick a way which is optimised and fast in processing.

Please answer your suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used a package in node.js called svg-captcha (link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-captcha) ; it is specifically built for avoiding google recaptcha (and the idea is simple so you might find similar packages for spring boot), basically the client calls for an image (svg) via an api to backend; which returns the image and encoded text. You can use the same idea for quick application. Although, i would not use it for serious applications. Good luck!